# Setting OCaml Binaries Directory Path for OcalDE

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ocaml

I would like to use the `OcalIDE plugin` to have `Ocaml` in my Eclipse.

I had installed the `ocaml-3.12.0-intel` on my Mac and then `OcalIDE plugi`n. But I couldn't make it finish as my `Ocaml` paths are all undefined.

I know my `Ocaml` package was installed at `/usr/local/lib/ocaml` as default, but the preference keep popping `value must be an existing file` error and I have no idea what was going wrong.

Any help from the floor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed OCaml in the standard locations, the path should be filled automatically. You can check in:

```
Window > Preferences > OcaIDE > Paths
```

Check also this really good tutorial : http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/tutorials/1-installing/installing.htm

Comment: Thank you so much for your info. I later found out that it was caused by the file permission problem as I wasn't login as root, so I changed the file permission and it works! Case closed =D